# How to check if a point is within bounded rectangle from Java

Tags: google-maps, java, google-maps-api, mysql, extents

I make an AJAX request to retrieve data from a `mysql` database. I add the data to `google.maps.Data` layer as geojson. I would only like to load the data based on the `viewport`. To obtain the viewport bounds I use:

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
```

With the bounds information, I have sent an AJAX request to my server to get the markers that are within those bounds.

I query the database table for all the data it has, can I instead query `mysql`only for the data contained within the bounds. If that is not an option, how do I check if a point is within the rectangle (on the server)?